# A pointwise proposition for $L^2(\mathbb{R}^3)$ functions

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, lp-spaces

Suppose $f\in L^2(\mathbb{R}^3)$, do we have that

$f(x)\rightarrow 0$ as $|x|\rightarrow \infty$?

If this proposition holds, how to prove it? If not, pls give a counter example.

Comment: In light of the given answers, perhaps you meant to specify that $f$ is continuous? If you have a clear idea of why you think this should be true, you should include it in the question, and we will be able to give you better help. If so, I recommend opening a new question (since this one is likely to be closed as poor-quality).

Answer (score 3):

No. Consider
$$
f(x) = \left\{
    \begin{array}{ll}
        1 & \mbox{if } x \in \mathbb{Q}^3 \\
        0 & \mbox{otherwise.}
    \end{array}
\right.
$$